# Spritebatch won't draw if I use rotation

Tags: c#, xna

I'm creating a game where the player is drawn in the middle of the screen. In order to modify the direction that the player is looking towards, I'm using the following lines of code:
In the player class, in the Draw() function:

```
//Draw player
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
   spriteBatch.Draw(currentTexture, position, null, Color.White, rotation, centre, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
}
```

I'm calling that function in the main class, inside the Draw() function:

```
//Draw
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
   GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
   spriteBatch.Begin();

   //Draw player
   player.Draw(spriteBatch);

   spriteBatch.End();
   base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

The player is not being drawn, and no error is showing up.

The weird thing is that I've used this exact same code for drawing in a game I made two days ago and it works fine.

If i use the following lines instead, the player is drawn, but i'm left without the ability to modify player rotation unless I use different textures for each direction:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(currentTexture, position, Color.White);
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is with were you set the origin. Your centre vector.  Try using Vector2.Zero instead of centre and see what happens.

Comment: Shouldn't `base.Draw(gameTime);` be called before you draw your player?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the problem is with were you set the origin. Your centre vector. Try using Vector2.Zero instead of centre and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For your center vector you probably want the center of the texture. The Vector2 center paramenter in SpriteBatch.Draw is relative to the texture coordinates. This means that to rotate around the center of your object you would need to have a value of

`new Vector2(texture.Width/2, texture.Height/2)`

I would recommend creating a method in your player class (Or GameObject class if you're doing that sort of thing) that returns your center with a texture coordinate relative Vector2 (like the one I provided above)! Happy Coding!